# sankeyNetwork is invisible in Shiny R

Tags: html, r, shiny, sankey-diagram, networkd3

[SOLVED]

I am trying to do a ShinyApp using some examples from the internet.
As part of my app I want to plot a Sankey Diagram, however, I have been finding a problem.

My app has a navbarPage structure and uses the example from https://github.com/jienagu/D3_folded_charts as one of the primary tabs. After some tests, I figured out that the sankeyNetwork was in conflict with the code part of the bar graph in the example above (specifically with this part: lines 147-149):

`output$airbar = renderD3({ bar_graphD3() })`

This is the code I am using to render the Sankey diagram:

```
  output$diagram <- networkD3::renderSankeyNetwork({
networkD3::sankeyNetwork(Links = dispersores_df, 
                         Nodes = nodes,
                         Source = "IDsource", 
                         Target = "IDtarget",
                         Value = "value", 
                         fontSize = 20,
                         NodeID = "name", 
                         sinksRight=FALSE)
```

})

Since this bar graph function is very important for my app, I can't remove it.

Also, due to the fact that the console doesn't pop up any error message, I realized the sankeyNetwork was been rendered. So, I changed my app structure to the fluidPage() and I found the Sankey graph was there (but it was not interactive) as you can see in the figure below.

[Sankey visualized in the fluidPage() structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdWFD.jpg)

After changing back to navbarPage() I inspected the tab the Sankey was, and it looks like it is there but invisible.

[Sankey invisible in the navbarPage() structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro6g8.jpg)

I found a similar report here [sankeyNetwork through renderUI disappears when applying JScode to remove viewbox with htmlwidgets::onRender()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418337/sankeynetwork-through-renderui-disappears-when-applying-jscode-to-remove-viewbox) but its solution didn't work for me.

Does anyone have any idea or clues that could help me?

Thanks

Full code here:

```
# library ------------------------------------------------------------------


if(!require("devtools")) install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("shiny")) install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("janitor")) install.packages("janitor", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("tidyverse")) install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("purrr")) install.packages("purrr", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("rlang")) install.packages("rlang", dependencies = TRUE)
#if(!require("stringr")) install.packages("stringr", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("noteMD")) devtools::install_github("jienagu/noteMD")
#if(!require("DT")) install.packages("DT", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("r2d3")) install.packages("r2d3", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("webshot")) install.packages("webshot", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("htmlwidgets")) install.packages("htmlwidgets", dependencies = TRUE)
#if(!require("memor")) install.packages("memor", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("shinyjs")) install.packages("shinyjs", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("nivopie")) devtools::install_github("jienagu/nivopie")
#if(!require("shinythemes")) install.packages("shinythemes", dependencies = TRUE)
#webshot::install_phantomjs()
#tinytex::install_tinytex()
if(!require("leaflet")) install.packages("leaflet", dependencies = TRUE)
#if(!require("performance")) install.packages("performance", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("shinyWidgets")) install.packages("shinyWidgets", dependencies = TRUE)
#if(!require("rmarkdown")) install.packages("rmarkdown", dependencies = TRUE)
if(!require("networkD3")) devtools::install_github("christophergandrud/networkD3")
#if(!require("stats")) install.packages("stats", dependencies = TRUE)
#if(!require("stargazer")) install.packages("stargazer", dependencies = TRUE)
#if(!require("caret")) install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)
#if(!require("sjPlot")) install.packages("sjPlot", dependencies = TRUE)
#if(!require("sjlabelled")) install.packages("sjlabelled", dependencies = TRUE)
#if(!require("sjmisc")) install.packages("sjmisc", dependencies = TRUE)


# ui ----------------------------------------------------------------------

col.list <- c("white")
colors <- paste0("background:",col.list,";")


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  div(style="display:inline-block", img(src="gif_trees_birds_grid_reseed.gif", 
                                         style="position: header; width: 100%; margin-left:0%; margin-top: 0%")),
  shinythemes::themeSelector(),
  navbarPage(
    theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
    title = "Atlantic forest plant traits",
    setBackgroundColor(color = c("#FFF5EE")),
    
    
    #header = tagList(
    #  useShinydashboard()
    #),
    
                        

# Pie graph ---------------------------------------------------------------
    
    tabPanel(title = "Traits Summary",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput(
                   inputId = "species",
                   label = "Species:",
                   selected = "Acnistus arborescens",
                   choices = c(unique(plant_traits$species)),
                   size = 25, selectize = FALSE
                 )
               ),
               
               # Show a plot of the generated distribution
               mainPanel(
                 tabsetPanel(
                   id = "tabs",
                   tabPanel(
                     title = "Analytics Dashboard",
                     value = "page1",
                     useShinyjs(),
                     checkboxInput("OneMore", label = h5("Show and Report donut Chart?"), T),
                     fluidRow(
                       column(
                         width = 6,
                         d3Output("traitbar")
                       ),
                       div(id='Hide',
                           column(
                             width = 6,
                             nivopieOutput("traitpie")
                           )
                       )
                     )
                   )
                 )
               )
             )
    ),


# dispersers --------------------------------------------------------------
    
        tabPanel(title = "Dispersers",
                   mainPanel(
                     tabsetPanel(type = "hidden",
                                 tabPanel("Animal dispersers",
                                          networkD3::sankeyNetworkOutput("diagram", 
                                                                         height = "700px", 
                                                                         width = "100%")))
                     
           ))


  )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  # Trait summary -----------------------------------------------------------
  
  
  shinyjs::useShinyjs()
  observe({
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Hide", condition = input$OneMore, anim = TRUE, animType = "fade")
  })
  plant_traits_filtered <- reactive({
    if (input$species != "ALL") plant_traits <- dplyr::filter(plant_traits, species == input$species)
    plant_traits
  })
  
  bar_graphD3 <- reactive({
    grouped <- ifelse(input$species != "ALL", expr(plant_traits), expr(species))
   
    spptraitdata <- plant_traits_filtered() %>%
      dplyr::group_by(!!grouped) %>%
      dplyr::tally() %>%
      dplyr::collect() %>%
      dplyr::mutate(
        y = n,
        x = !!grouped) %>%
      dplyr::select(x, y)

    spptraitdata <- spptraitdata %>%
      dplyr::mutate(label = x)
    
    r2d3::r2d3(spptraitdata, "bar_plot.js")
  })
  
  pie_graph <- reactive({
    grouped2 <- ifelse(input$species != "ALL", expr(plant_traits), expr(species))
    
    spptraitdata2 <- plant_traits_filtered() %>%
      dplyr::group_by(!!grouped2) %>%
      dplyr::tally() %>%
      dplyr::collect() %>%
      dplyr::mutate(
        value = n,
        id = !!grouped2) %>%
      dplyr::select(id, value)
    
    spptraitdata3 <- data.frame(spptraitdata2)
    spptraitdata3$id <- as.factor(spptraitdata3$id)
    nivopie::nivopie(spptraitdata3, innerRadius=0.5, cornerRadius=5, fit=T, sortByValue=T,
            colors='paired', enableRadialLabels=F, radialLabelsLinkDiagonalLength=1,
            radialLabelsLinkHorizontalLength=8,
            enableSlicesLabels=T, sliceLabel='id',isInteractive=T)
    
  })

  output$traitbar = r2d3::renderD3({
    bar_graphD3()
  })

  output$traitpie=nivopie::renderNivopie({
    pie_graph()
  })
  
  # plant/trait bar click (server) ---------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$bar_clicked != "", {
    if (input$species == "ALL") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "species", selected = input$bar_clicked)
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  

# sankeyNetwork diagram plot ------------------------------------------------------

  
  output$diagram <- networkD3::renderSankeyNetwork({
    networkD3::sankeyNetwork(Links = dispersores_df, 
                             Nodes = nodes,
                             Source = "IDsource", 
                             Target = "IDtarget",
                             Value = "value", 
                             fontSize = 20,
                             NodeID = "name", 
                             sinksRight=FALSE) #%>% 
#      htmlwidgets::onRender('function(el) { el.querySelector("svg").removeAttribute("viewBox") }')
    
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I believe there are some packages listed here that are not required to reproduce. You'd have more chance that somebody tries to help you if they don't have to install them all. Also please remove all the `install.packages()` or at least comment them)

Comment: I just added the argument "d3_version = 3" inside the function r2d3::r2d3(spptraitdata, "bar_plot.js", d3_version = 3) and it worked. It also solved a posterior problem I had with collapsibleTree::collapsibleTree, which was been plotted but wasn't interactive due to some problem with r2d3.